# In the Maven Standard Directory Layout where do I put Rules Engine files?

Tags: maven, directory, drools

In the Maven Standard Directory Layout where do I put Rules Engine files?  Specifically, I'm using JBoss Rules (Drools), if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

In our project, we just put them in `src/main/resources/`.  They need to end up on the classpath, but aren't Java code, so that seemed like the obvious place to put them.

You could also create a separate resource directory like `src/main/drools/`, but then you'd have to define it explicitly in the POM file so that it gets onto the classpath.  If you've got lots of other kinds of resources already cluttering up `src/main/resources/`, then a separate dir is probably the way to go.  If the rules files are your only resources, I would hold off on making a separate directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you are **not precompiling** them in your build (this is the default behaviour), put them under `src/main/resources/`. For the build, they are no different from other resources like image, property and xml files: just copy them to `target/classes`.

However, if you are using one of the experimental maven plugins and if it supports precompiling and you are **precompiling** them, then put them under `src/main/drools/` so the build can precompile them and output them to `target/classes`.

The thing to understand is that `src/main/java/` and `src/main/webapp/` are distinct from `src/main/resources/` because the build treats each one differently (either doing something during the copy or copying to a different location).